# 'HELP' Procedure or Funtion 'LOCAL_InsTKill' has too many arguments specified

Tags: sql-server

How to fix this?

```
ALTER      procedure [dbo].[LOCAL_InsTKill]     
    @char_id    int
    ,@pk_char_id    int
    ,@pk_char_type  int 
    ,@pk_second int 
    ,@isKill        tinyint
    ,@mode_type  int        
as          
set nocount on          
declare @ret    int 
insert into TKill (char_id, pk_char_id, pk_char_type, pk_second, isKill, mode_type)
    values(@char_id, @pk_char_id, @pk_char_type, @pk_second, @isKill, @mode_type)
set @ret = @@error          
if @@rowcount <> 1 and @ret = 0 set @ret = -1           
return @ret
```

I have error in exec @ret = LOCAL_InsTKill @char_id, @pk_char_id, @pk_char_type, @pk_second, @isKill, @modestates, @guildname
error message Procedure or Function 'LOCAL_InsTKill' has too many argument specified

```
ALTER    procedure [dbo].[ROHAN_InsertKill]     
    @char_id    int
    ,@pk_char_id    int 
    ,@pk_char_type  int 
    ,@pk_second int 
    ,@isKill        tinyint
    ,@modestates        int
    ,@guildname varchar(20)     
as          
set nocount on          
declare @ret    int 
begin tran          
exec @ret = LOCAL_InsTKill @char_id, @pk_char_id, @pk_char_type, @pk_second, @isKill, @modestates, @guildname           
if @ret <> 0 goto ERR           
commit          
return @ret         
ERR:            
rollback            
return @ret
```

Comment: Look at your first piece of code. After `@IsKill`, it only have one more parameter, `@mode_type`. In your call, you're trying to pass `@modestates` *and* `@guildname`. What actual assistance do you need here?

Answer (score 0):

In your `LOCAL_InsTKill` procedure, these are the parameters you have specified. There are 6 parameters.

```
@char_id
@pk_char_id
@pk_char_type
@pk_second
@isKill
@mode_type
```

But in your `ROHAN_InsertKill` procedure, you're trying to pass 7 parameters to the `LOCAL_InsTKill` procedure which is causing the issue.

> procedure or Function 'LOCAL_InsTKill' has too many argument specified

```
exec @ret = LOCAL_InsTKill @char_id, @pk_char_id, @pk_char_type, @pk_second, @isKill, @modestates, @guildname   

@char_id
@pk_char_id
@pk_char_type
@pk_second
@isKill

@modestates -- Recommended suitable renaming Ex:mode_type  
@guildname -- Not in the LOCAL_InsTKill procedure
```

You can resolve this easily by either removing `@guildname` from `ROHAN_InsertKill` procedure or by adding `@guildname` as a parameter to the `LOCAL_InsTKill` procedure.